# d3.js Search functionality in collapsible tree

Tags: d3.js, hierarchy

I have created my visualization similar to the http://mbostock.github.com/d3/talk/20111018/tree.html. I wish end users  to be able to search for node/data/label from the tree. Since I am not good with javascript I am finding quite hard to create such search functionality.

Here are my requirements: End users can type text like 'cluster' (flare->analytics-->cluster) and type enter. The visualization highlights cluster and shows to the end users.

If it is possible could you share the code using jsfiddle?

Answer (score 0):

Not sure if this question is still valid but a D3 node tree version that I found that really helped is this one:

[Jake Zieve's "Search Collapsible Tree](https://bl.ocks.org/jjzieve/a743242f46321491a950)

Let me know if this helps.  The code should be pretty similar to the one you attached.  Either way, let me know if this will lead you on the right path.